# How to decrement Timer variable - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, decrement

Well, I have two TIMER type variables in my code AS3, but there comes a certain part
of my game, I have to decrement the value of them.

```
var tempo1:Timer = new Timer(4000);
var tParada:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1);
```

I wonder how can I do to go decrementing these values, starting from an external class ...

Thank U.

Comment: What scope are these variables defined in? Are they instance variables? Are they at the timeline? You can always change the time of a timer instance with it's *.delay* property IF you can access that timer instance.

Comment: Friend, she is on stage ... I have access to it through an external class ...
Could you give me an example of how decrement her time?

Comment: If you have access to them, you just decrement the timer like this: tempo1.delay = 100; //100 millis. Same with the tParada. Suerte.

Comment: I understand, but if I wanted to go gradually diminishing? Ex .: tempo1.delay - = 100? Thank U!

Comment: You can tween it, if that's what your getting at.   `TweenLite.to(tempo1, 2, {delay: tempo1.delay - 100, ease: Quad.easeOut})`  That would lower the delay by 100 over a period of 2 seconds.   TweenLite is an external library from greensock, if you don't charge for your app, it's free* to use.   There is a built in Tween class too that can do the same thing

Comment: Cool! But natively AS3 not of this support, or would not have a native way to recover the value of time and decrement it? is that I already have almost all the game ready, and never used this Tweenlite library.

Hugs.

Comment: The delay property is get/set. So I assume you could use it like  tempo1.delay -= 100

Comment: Btw I strongly recommend you using the AS3 documentation (it is actually pretty good) where you can check these things: Here is the delay prop: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decriment the delay every time the timer fires.

```
var tempo1:Timer = new Timer(4000);
tempo1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
var minValue:int = 1000;

tempo1.start();

function tick(e:TimerEvent):void {
    if(tempo1.delay - 100 >= minValue){
        tempo1.delay -= 100;
    }
}
```

Or, if wanted it smoother, you could do something like this:

```
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

var tempo1:Timer = new Timer(33); //30 times a seconds or so
    tempo1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
    var curTickTime:int = 4000;

    tempo1.start();

    function tick(e:TimerEvent):void {
        if(tempo1.delay * tempo1.currentCount >= curTickTime){
            trace("tick"); //this should effectively be a tick
            tempo1.reset();
            tempo1.start();

            //do whatever you do on a tick
        }
    }

//tween the tick delay from the starting value to 100ms over a period of 5 seconds
var tween:Tween = new Tween(this, "curTickTime", Strong.easeOut, curTickTime, 100, 5, true);
```